# Get the code from remote system after code changes

Tags: git, github

Here I want to get the code from remote system when the code is updating      after client side.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting you want to update your local repository, if there has been any change from client side on remote server.

```
git pull origin branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is updated from client side and committed to remote repo, "yes" you can get the changes from remote. 
Its simple,
Just go inside of the project through the terminal and type following command and then press enter,

```
$ git pull
```

If the client side created new branch and committed those changes to repo,

```
$ git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

change the  to real branch name of the project branch

Comment: in git pull command I assume that you are working on the same local branch which is checked out from remote